# Flutter text to speech: Speech rate varing from devide to device

Tags: flutter

I have build a app to read the text, but speech rate is varying from device to device.  Its much faster in IOS ad compared to any Android device. Below is the code I am using.  Any suggestios are welcome!

```
await flutterTts.setLanguage('en-US');
await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(0.95);
await flutterTts.speak("I am A flutter developer");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a difference between platforms. On iOS the range is between 0 to 1.0. On Android it looks like it's 0 to 2.0 ([source](https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts/pull/72)). Apparently it's not linear either so doing a simple range mapping wouldn't work. A workaround other users are doing is to do this:

```dart
FlutterTts().setSpeechRate(Platform.isAndroid ? 0.8 : 0.395);
```

There is an [open issue here](https://github.com/dlutton/flutter_tts/issues/109) discussing the need to have a uniform `speechRate` for both platforms but nothing yet.

(also, digging through old issues is a good way to find your answers when it comes to package specific issues)

Comment: Thank you very much!!